# Difference in performance of compiled accelerate code ran from ghci and shell

Tags: performance, haskell, profiling, ghci, accelerate-haskell

**Problem**

Hello, I'm using accelerate library to create an application allowing the user to interactively call functions that process images, that's why I'm basing on and extending ghci using ghc api.

The problem is that when running the compiled executable from the shell the computations are done under 100ms (slightly less than 80), while running the same compiled code within ghci it takes over 100ms (on average a bit more than 140) to finish.

**Resources**

sample code + execution logs:
https://gist.github.com/zgredzik/15a437c87d3d8d03b8fc

**Description**

First of all: the tests were ran after the CUDA kernel was compiled (the compilation itself added additional 2 seconds but that's not the case).

When running the compiled executable from the shell the computations are done in under 10ms. (`shell first run` and `second shell run` have different arguments passed to make sure the data wasn't cached anywhere).

When trying to run the same code from ghci and fiddling with the input data, the computations take over 100ms. I understand that interpreted code is slower than compiled one, but I'm loading the same compiled code within the ghci session and calling the same top level binding (`packedFunction`). I've explicitly typed it to make sure it is specialized (same results as using the SPECIALIZED pragma).

However the computations do take less than 10ms if I run the `main` function in ghci (even when changing the input data with `:set args` between consecutive calls).

Compiled the `Main.hs` with `ghc -o main Main.hs -O2 -dynamic -threaded`

I'm wondering where the overhead comes from. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening?

---

A simplified version of the example posted by [remdezx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641629/remdezx) :

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Data.Array.Accelerate as A
import Data.Array.Accelerate.CUDA as C
import Data.Time.Clock       (diffUTCTime, getCurrentTime)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    start <- getCurrentTime
    print $ C.run $ A.maximum $ A.map (+1) $ A.use (fromList (Z:.1000000) [1..1000000] :: Vector Double)
    end   <- getCurrentTime
    print $ diffUTCTime end start
```

When I compile it and execute it takes **0,09s** to finish.

```
$ ghc -O2 Main.hs -o main -threaded
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking main ...
$ ./main
Array (Z) [1000001.0]
0.092906s
```

But when I precompile it and run in interpreter it takes **0,25s**

```
$ ghc -O2 Main.hs -c -dynamic
$ ghci Main
ghci> main
Array (Z) [1000001.0]
0.258224s
```

Comment: Could you turn on profiling and get a report?

Comment: you mean like here: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html ?

I'll try asap.

Comment: I've injected some time measurement code into `Data.Array.Accelerate.CUDA.run` and I've noticed that when `acclerate` library is loaded to ghci, `run` executes 3 times slower than when its used in executable. I tried adding following pragmas but no effect.
`{-# SPECIALISE run :: Acc (Array DIM2 Double) -> (Array DIM2 Double) #-}
    {-# SPECIALISE run :: Acc (Array DIM2 Float) -> (Array DIM2 Float) #-}`.
Can we optimize somehow this run function for ghci?

Comment: I've updated the gist – added the profiling report (main.prof)

Comment: Are you sure that ghci is loading the compiled and optimized module? Could you try the invocation in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27881725/1186208)? In my experience, `$ ghc -O2 Test.hs && ghci Test` results in ghci recompiling `Test` in interpreted mode because the flags changed. (No `-O2` in the second invocation.)  I don't know if that's relevant to `accelerate`. I can't test this example--I don't have a CUDA system handy--so I'm hesitant to post an answer.

Comment: @ChristianConkle: I cannot test it now by myself (I'm working together with @KonradMadej). They will test it tommorow. If you would like and be so nice, we can provide you tommorow a EC2 Amazon instance with all set up (including cuda environment) so we can make together tests. I see you know more about this topic, so If yo uagree we can get some results there? :) Anyway we will try what you have describbed and I will write back :)

Comment: @ChristianConkle we are quite sure ghci loads the compiled and optimized module (while it's true we had a bit of trouble with that, the `-dynamic` flag seemed to have solved the problem). This may be indicated by a) the part in logs from ghci where `> :l Main` results in `Ok, modules loaded: Main.` (instead of `[1 of 1] Compiling Main ( Main.hs, interpreted )`) ; b) running `:show modules` results in `Main ( Main.hs, Main.o )` (should've had that in the logs too I guess)

Comment: @ChristianConkle, I also tested running ghci with `-fobject-code` and `-O2` - this also makes ghci to load precompiled code (we can see ith running `:show modules`, but there is still no speedup. Something still remains not optimized.

Comment: The `Ok, modules loaded: Main.` just indicates that ghci didn't recompile or reinterpret the module. It's conceivable that the module it loads is compiled but not optimized--in my testing, I found several corner cases where it was not obvious whether the loaded object code was optimized. If you want to be completely sure, you can use the example code from the other topic, which proves whether the rewrite rule (and presumably other optimizations) worked. That said, it would make sense if something other than GHC optimizations makes a difference here.

Comment: @ChristianConkle, I tried your test from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881725/how-can-i-load-optimized-code-in-ghci and injected this rewrite rule into accelerate-cuda library - result: `isOptimised=True`, but code is still slow.

Comment: @remdezx - That makes sense. I glanced at `accelerate` a few days ago, and it didn't look like it was designed to rely heavily on GHC optimizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I investigated `accelerate` and `accelerate-cuda` and put some debug code to measure a time both under ghci and in a compiled, optimised version.

Results are below, you can see stack trace and execution times.

**ghci run**

```
$ ghc -O2 -dynamic -c -threaded Main.hs && ghci 
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
…
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
Prelude Main> Loading package transformers-0.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
…
Loading package array-0.5.0.0 ... linking ... done.
(...)
Loading package accelerate-cuda-0.15.0.0 ... linking ... done.
>>>>> run
>>>>> runAsyncIn.execute
>>>>>  runAsyncIn.seq ctx
<<<<<  runAsyncIn.seq ctx: 4.1609e-2 CPU  0.041493s TOTAL
>>>>>  runAsyncIn.seq a
<<<<<  runAsyncIn.seq a: 1.0e-6 CPU  0.000001s TOTAL
>>>>>  runAsyncIn.seq acc
>>>>>   convertAccWith True
<<<<<   convertAccWith: 0.0 CPU  0.000017s TOTAL
<<<<<  runAsyncIn.seq acc: 2.68e-4 CPU  0.000219s TOTAL
>>>>>  evalCUDA
>>>>>   push
<<<<<   push: 0.0 CPU  0.000002s TOTAL
>>>>>   evalStateT
>>>>>    runAsyncIn.compileAcc
>>>>>     compileOpenAcc
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Alet
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Use
>>>>>       compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.use3
>>>>>       compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.use1
<<<<<       compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.use1: 0.0 CPU  0.000001s TOTAL
>>>>>       compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.use2
>>>>>        compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.seq arr
<<<<<        compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.seq arr: 0.105716 CPU  0.105501s TOTAL
>>>>>        useArrayAsync
<<<<<        useArrayAsync: 1.234e-3 CPU  0.001505s TOTAL
<<<<<       compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.use2: 0.108012 CPU  0.108015s TOTAL
<<<<<       compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.use3: 0.108539 CPU  0.108663s TOTAL
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Use: 0.109375 CPU  0.109005s TOTAL
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Fold1
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar: 0.0 CPU  0.000001s TOTAL
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar: 0.0 CPU  0s TOTAL
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar: 0.0 CPU  0.000001s TOTAL
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar: 0.0 CPU  0s TOTAL
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Fold1: 2.059e-3 CPU  0.002384s TOTAL
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Alet: 0.111434 CPU  0.112034s TOTAL
<<<<<     compileOpenAcc: 0.11197 CPU  0.112615s TOTAL
<<<<<    runAsyncIn.compileAcc: 0.11197 CPU  0.112833s TOTAL
>>>>>    runAsyncIn.dumpStats
<<<<<    runAsyncIn.dumpStats: 2.0e-6 CPU  0.000001s TOTAL
>>>>>    runAsyncIn.executeAcc
>>>>>     executeAcc
<<<<<     executeAcc: 8.96e-4 CPU  0.00049s TOTAL
<<<<<    runAsyncIn.executeAcc: 9.36e-4 CPU  0.0007s TOTAL
>>>>>    runAsyncIn.collect
<<<<<    runAsyncIn.collect: 0.0 CPU  0.000027s TOTAL
<<<<<   evalStateT: 0.114156 CPU  0.115327s TOTAL
>>>>>   pop
<<<<<   pop: 0.0 CPU  0.000002s TOTAL
>>>>>   performGC
<<<<<   performGC: 5.7246e-2 CPU  0.057814s TOTAL
<<<<<  evalCUDA: 0.17295 CPU  0.173943s TOTAL
<<<<< runAsyncIn.execute: 0.215475 CPU  0.216563s TOTAL
<<<<< run: 0.215523 CPU  0.216771s TOTAL
Array (Z) [1000001.0]
0.217148s
Prelude Main> Leaving GHCi.
```

**compiled code run**

```
$ ghc -O2 -threaded Main.hs && ./Main
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking Main ...
>>>>> run
>>>>> runAsyncIn.execute
>>>>>  runAsyncIn.seq ctx
<<<<<  runAsyncIn.seq ctx: 4.0639e-2 CPU  0.041498s TOTAL
>>>>>  runAsyncIn.seq a
<<<<<  runAsyncIn.seq a: 1.0e-6 CPU  0.000001s TOTAL
>>>>>  runAsyncIn.seq acc
>>>>>   convertAccWith True
<<<<<   convertAccWith: 1.2e-5 CPU  0.000005s TOTAL
<<<<<  runAsyncIn.seq acc: 1.15e-4 CPU  0.000061s TOTAL
>>>>>  evalCUDA
>>>>>   push
<<<<<   push: 2.0e-6 CPU  0.000002s TOTAL
>>>>>   evalStateT
>>>>>    runAsyncIn.compileAcc
>>>>>     compileOpenAcc
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Alet
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Use
>>>>>       compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.use3
>>>>>       compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.use1
<<<<<       compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.use1: 0.0 CPU  0.000001s TOTAL
>>>>>       compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.use2
>>>>>        compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.seq arr
<<<<<        compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.seq arr: 3.6651e-2 CPU  0.03712s TOTAL
>>>>>        useArrayAsync
<<<<<        useArrayAsync: 1.427e-3 CPU  0.001427s TOTAL
<<<<<       compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.use2: 3.8776e-2 CPU  0.039152s TOTAL
<<<<<       compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.use3: 3.8794e-2 CPU  0.039207s TOTAL
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Use: 3.8808e-2 CPU  0.03923s TOTAL
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Fold1
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar: 2.0e-6 CPU  0.000001s TOTAL
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar: 2.0e-6 CPU  0.000001s TOTAL
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar: 0.0 CPU  0.000001s TOTAL
>>>>>      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Avar: 0.0 CPU  0.000001s TOTAL
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Fold1: 1.342e-3 CPU  0.001284s TOTAL
<<<<<      compileOpenAcc.traveuseAcc.Alet: 4.0197e-2 CPU  0.040578s TOTAL
<<<<<     compileOpenAcc: 4.0248e-2 CPU  0.040895s TOTAL
<<<<<    runAsyncIn.compileAcc: 4.0834e-2 CPU  0.04103s TOTAL
>>>>>    runAsyncIn.dumpStats
<<<<<    runAsyncIn.dumpStats: 0.0 CPU  0s TOTAL
>>>>>    runAsyncIn.executeAcc
>>>>>     executeAcc
<<<<<     executeAcc: 2.87e-4 CPU  0.000403s TOTAL
<<<<<    runAsyncIn.executeAcc: 2.87e-4 CPU  0.000488s TOTAL
>>>>>    runAsyncIn.collect
<<<<<    runAsyncIn.collect: 9.2e-5 CPU  0.000049s TOTAL
<<<<<   evalStateT: 4.1213e-2 CPU  0.041739s TOTAL
>>>>>   pop
<<<<<   pop: 0.0 CPU  0.000002s TOTAL
>>>>>   performGC
<<<<<   performGC: 9.41e-4 CPU  0.000861s TOTAL
<<<<<  evalCUDA: 4.3308e-2 CPU  0.042893s TOTAL
<<<<< runAsyncIn.execute: 8.5154e-2 CPU  0.084815s TOTAL
<<<<< run: 8.5372e-2 CPU  0.085035s TOTAL
Array (Z) [1000001.0]
0.085169s
```

As we can see there are two major problems: evaluation of `fromList (Z:.1000000) [1..1000000] :: Vector Double` which takes **69 ms** extra under ghci (106ms - 37ms), and `performGC` call which takes **57 ms** extra (58 ms - 1 ms). These two sum up to the difference between execution under ghci and in a compiled version.

I suppose, that in compiled program, RTS manage memory in a different way than in ghci, so allocation and gc can be faster. We can also test only this part evaluating below code (it does not require CUDA at all):

```
import Data.Array.Accelerate.Array.Sugar
import Data.Time.Clock                   (diffUTCTime, getCurrentTime)
import System.Mem                        (performGC)


main :: IO ()
main = do
    measure $ seq (fromList (Z:.1000000) [1..1000000] :: Vector Double) $ return ()
    measure $ performGC

measure action = do
    start <- getCurrentTime
    action
    end   <- getCurrentTime
    print $ diffUTCTime end start
```

**Results:**

- evaluating vector takes **0.121653s** under ghci and **0.035162s** in
  a compiled version
- performGC takes **0.044876s** under ghci and
  **0.00031s** in a compiled version.

This could be another question, but maybe someone know: **Can we tune somehow garbage collector to work faster under ghci?**