# How can I load optimized code in GHCI?

Tags: haskell, ghc, compiler-optimization, read-eval-print-loop, ghci

I am writing a module that relies on optimization. I want to test this module in ghci. But starting ghc in `--interactive` mode automatically disables optimization; if I compile the module with `-O` and then try to load it in an interactive session, `ghc` insists on loading it in interpreted mode.

For a simple test case to distinguish optimized and unoptimized modules, `isOptimized` below evaluates to `True` with optimization on, but `False` with optimization off:

```
isOptimized :: Bool
isOptimized = g

g :: Bool
g = False

{-# NOINLINE g #-}
{-# RULES "g/True"  g = True #-}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either use `ghci -fobject-code -O Test.hs` or `cabal repl --ghc-options="-fobject-code -O"`. In more detail:

1. ghci must be invoked with the [`-fobject-code` flag](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-obj.html).
2. Optimization flag(s) must be given *after* `-fobject-code` on the command line, or in an OPTIONS_GHC pragma at the top of the module. Trying `ghc --interactive -O -fobject-code` produces a warning that "-O conflicts with --interactive; -O ignored." This is perhaps a bug.
3. If you're working on a cabalized project and using `cabal repl`, you need to pass the flags either on the command line (i.e. `cabal repl --ghc-options="-fobject-code -O"`) or in a pragma. Cabal (currently) discards optimization flags set in the .cabal file with `ghc-options` when invoking ghci; in fact, it explicitly sets `-O0` instead. This is perhaps a bug.

Note in any case that you sometimes need to force recompilation manually when switching between optimized and unoptimized mode. Build artifacts are, for some reason, not invalidated when the optimization flags change so long as `-fobject-code` remains on. If, starting from a clean slate, you have `-fobject-code` set in your .cabal file, run `cabal repl` which compiles the module, and then remember you need to set -O on the command line and run `cabal repl --ghc-options=-O`, ghc will happily load the previously-compiled, unoptimized module. This is also perhaps a bug.

The most reliable scenario for testing a single module seems to be to put `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fobject-code -O #-}` at the top of the module. You will get optimized code no matter how you invoke ghci. I haven't investigated what happens in multi-module situations where some but not all modules have the pragma.

Incidentally, note that only code *in the module* is optimized. Even with optimization on, evaluating `g` in the repl will always produce `False`, because the repl input is not subject to rewrite rules.

Comment: So it seems to me this could be a way to actually time functions and roughly measure performances through GHCi. Can you or anyone approve or disapprove?

Comment: @ChristianConkle have you seen this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541609/difference-in-performance-of-compiled-accelerate-code-ran-from-ghci-and-shell

Comment: @WojciechDanilo - Yes. I just posted a comment there. (I don't think I can @ notify you in that topic because you haven't commented yet.)

Comment: I [crash](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10965) when I try including `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fobject-code -O #-}`.